# How do I update a value in XAML when an action is performed from somewhere other than the direct code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am having a bit of a dilemma. Over some time I have been working on a plugin for an application called SimHub which for the most part does work. I'm heading into a phase where I want to keep improving it and adding more features.

What part of my plugin does is sets a property value for use inside the application. The setting of this is done inside of a "Settings page" and when the value is changed it updates an entry in a .json file. That entry in the .json is then read and assigned to a property.

The improvement I am trying to do is this. You can also add "actions" which is the setting of a keyboard shortcut. that shortcut will then do a defined thing. The action I am trying to add is 2 keys. One key to increment the value by 0.1 and another key to decrement the value by 0.1.

I have managed to successfully add the action and it works in as much as  it will increment or decrement the value in the settings .json file and the property is updated. What I wanted to achieve though is that when the keys are used for incrementing or decrementing the value I also want the value to be shown in the settings screen.

Here is the relevant code below. There is a fair bit so please forgive me. I have omitted everything that is irrelevant.

**Main Code**

```cs
public class OMSCPlugin : IPlugin, IDataPlugin, IWPFSettings, IWPFSettingsV2
{
    public OMSCPluginSettings Settings;

    public void Init(PluginManager pluginManager)
    {
        Logging.Current.Info((object)($"Starting plugin: OMSC Plugin - Version {VersionText}"));
        this.Settings = this.ReadCommonSettings<OMSCPluginSettings>("Settings", (Func<OMSCPluginSettings>)(() => new OMSCPluginSettings()));
        this.AttachDelegate<OMSCPlugin, double>("Settings.ACC.FuelSafetyBuffer", (Func<double>)(() => this.Settings.ACCFuelSafetyBuffer));

        this.AddAction("IncrementFSB", (a, b) =>
        {
            Settings.ACCFuelSafetyBuffer += 0.1;
            this.SaveCommonSettings<OMSCPluginSettings>("Settings", this.Settings);
        });
        this.AddAction("DecrementFSB", (a, b) =>
        {
            Settings.ACCFuelSafetyBuffer -= 0.1;
            this.SaveCommonSettings<OMSCPluginSettings>("Settings", this.Settings);
        });
    }
}
```

**XAML** (*excluded a bunch of irrelevant stuff*)

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="OzrickMajor.OMSCPlugin.OMSCPluginSettingsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:OzrickMajor.OMSCPlugin"
             xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:OzrickMajor.OMSCPlugin.Sections"
             xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             xmlns:styles="clr-namespace:SimHub.Plugins.Styles;assembly=SimHub.Plugins"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:SimHub.Plugins.UI;assembly=SimHub.Plugins"
             xmlns:wpfui="clr-namespace:SimHub.Plugins.OutputPlugins.Dash.WPFUI;assembly=SimHub.Plugins"
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit">

<mah:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  ValueChanged="ACCFuelSafetyBuffer_ValueChanged" x:Name="_accfuelsafetybuffer" Width="170"
                   Minimum="0.1" Maximum="5.0" Interval="0.1" StringFormat="0.0" HasDecimals="True" Cursor="Hand"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"
       Content="Fuel Safety Buffer (in Laps)"/>
<ui:ControlsEditor Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FriendlyName="Increment FSB" ActionName="OMSCPlugin.IncrementFSB"/>
<ui:ControlsEditor Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FriendlyName="Decrement FSB" ActionName="OMSCPlugin.DecrementFSB"/>
```

**XAML Code Behind**

```cs
public partial class OMSCPluginSettingsControl : UserControl, IComponentConnector
{
    public OMSCPlugin Plugin { get; }

    public PluginManager PluginManager { get; internal set; }

    public OMSCPluginSettingsControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public OMSCPluginSettingsControl(OMSCPlugin plugin) : this()
    {
        this.Plugin = plugin;
        this._accfuelsafetybuffer.Value = this.Plugin.Settings.ACCFuelSafetyBuffer;
    }

    public void ACCFuelSafetyBuffer_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Plugin.Settings.ACCFuelSafetyBuffer = Math.Round((double)this._accfuelsafetybuffer.Value, 1);
        this.Plugin.SaveCommonSettings<OMSCPluginSettings>("Settings", this.Plugin.Settings);
    }
}
```

**Settings File Code**

```
public class OMSCPluginSettings
{
    public double ACCFuelSafetyBuffer { get; set; } = 1.5;
}
```

---

I have tried to achieve what I need with a {Binding Path=ACCFuelSafetyBuffer} in the "Value" parameter of the xaml like this:

```xml
<mah:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  ValueChanged="ACCFuelSafetyBuffer_ValueChanged" x:Name="_accfuelsafetybuffer" Width="170"
                   Minimum="0.1" Maximum="5.0" Interval="0.1" StringFormat="0.0" HasDecimals="True" Cursor="Hand" 
                   Value="{Binding Path=ACCFuelSafetyBuffer}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"
       Content="Fuel Safety Buffer (in Laps)"/>
```

When I compile and check within the application however the box is just blank and doesn't display the value even though the value is there in the settings file and has been applied to the property and still changes when pressing the keys. My assumption is that my binding doesn't actually go anywhere hence, the blank box, even though I am not getting any compiler errors or runtime errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd like to do this without adding too much extra code as another goal of mine recently has been slimming down a lot of the unnecessary code from when I first started learning C# and writing the plugin.

Comment: Read about [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-8.0) and [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

The `OMSCPluginSettings` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ACCFuelSafetyBuffer` property to notify the view that the source property has changed:

```
public class OMSCPluginSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _accFuelSafetyBuffer = 1.5;
    public double ACCFuelSafetyBuffer
    {
        get { return _accFuelSafetyBuffer; }
        set { _accFuelSafetyBuffer = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```